# C++ Subclass Constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am having trouble understanding how to construct a subclass. My parent class is called "package" and the children are called "overnight" and "twoDay". The package class handles the recipient's name and address as well as the packages weight and the shipping cost per oz. twoDay also adds an additional shipping fee and overnight adds more to the shipping cost per oz.

The package class files run fine but I can't figure out how to use it in the children constructors. Below I will show the files for package and overnight and the header area of the main program file.

**program.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "package.h"
#include "twoDay.h"
#include "overnight.h"

int main() {

}
```

**package.h**

```
#include <string>
#include "name.h"
#include "address.h"

class package {
 public:
  package();
  package(std::string initFirst, std::string initLast, std::string initLineOne,
          std::string initLineTwo, std::string initCity, std::string initState,
          std::string initZip, double initWeight, double initPrice);
  double getWeight() const;
  double getPrice() const;
  double getCost() const;
 private:
  name recipientName;
  address recipientAddress;
  double weight;
  double price;
};
```

**package.cpp**

```
#include "package.h"

package::package(){
  recipientName = name();
  recipientAddress = address();
  weight = 0.0;
  price = 0.0;
}

package::package(std::string initFirst, std::string initLast, std::string initLineOne,
                 std::string initLineTwo, std::string initCity, std::string initState,
                 std::string initZip, double initWeight, double initPrice)
  : recipientName(initFirst,initLast), recipientAddress(initLineOne,initLineTwo,initCity,initState,initZip) {
  weight = initWeight;
  price = initPrice;
}
```

**overnight.h**

```
#include <string>

class overnight : public package {
 public:
  overnight();
  overnight(std::string initFirst, std::string initLast, std::string initLineOne,
            std::string initLineTwo, std::string initCity, std::string initState,
            std::string initZip, double initWeight, double initPrice, double initOunceFee);
  double getOvernightCost() const;
 private:
  package packageInfo;
  double ounceFee;
};
```

**overnight.cpp**

```
#include "overnight.h"

overnight::overnight() {
  packageInfo = package();
  ounceFee = 0.0;
}

overnight::overnight(std::string initFirst, std::string initLast, std::string initLineOne,
                     std::string initLineTwo, std::string initCity, std::string initState,
                     std::string initZip, double initWeight, double initPrice, double initOunceFee)
  : packageInfo(initFirst,initLast,initLineOne,initLineTwo,initCity,initState,initZip,initWeight,initPrice){
  ounceFee = initOunceFee;
}
```

So the part I'm having trouble with is the second constructor of overnight.cpp with the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `overnight` *is a* `package`, you don't need composition and embed a `package` object in the class.

As for the constructor, do e.g.

```
overnight::overnight(std::string initFirst, std::string initLast, std::string initLineOne,
    std::string initLineTwo, std::string initCity, std::string initState,
    std::string initZip, double initWeight, double initPrice, double initOunceFee)
: package(initFirst,initLast,initLineOne,initLineTwo,initCity,initState,initZip,initWeight,initPrice){
//^^^^^^^ Note the use of the base class here
    ounceFee = initOunceFee;
}
```

Comment: That is how I thought it worked but it gave me the following errors: http://imgur.com/L43qOWQ

Comment: @JohnLongsocks Where do you include the `"package.h"` header file?

Comment: @JoichimPilebord it is included in the "package.cpp" and the "program.cpp" file. Since it is include first in the "program.cpp" file doesn't that mean that the files after it will also have access to it?

Comment: @JohnLongsocks don't do that. Make sure your base class headers are included in your *derived* class headers. Don't build a compilation dependency on the ordering of an include-file list of a translation unit. If a header `derived.h` needs stuff from a different header `foo.h`, then `#include "foo.h"` inside the header guards of `derived.h`. This is true for *all* header dependencies. Your "overnight.h" should include "package.h", and <string> (as it uses `std::string` as well). And you should have proper include-guards.

Comment: @JohnLongsocks glad to help. It may seem a little odd at first, but you ideally also include user-defined headers *before* standard library headers. It may look a little odd at first, but the reason is sound: it prevents you from accidentally building an ordering dependency just as i described above. For example, `"package.h"` includes `<string>`, then `"name.h"`, and `"address.h"` If `name.h` accidentally forgot to include `<string>` and it uses `std::string` someone that include *just* `name.h` would fail to compile, but including `package.h` and they would succeed.....

Comment: @JohnLongsocks you can avoid that problem by always including user-headers *first*. That ensures any additional dependencies are fulfilled *prior* to pulling in additional library headers, thereby making your user-defined headers more stand-alone and self-dependency fulfilling. Hope that makes sense. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig What about when I have two derived classes? If I try adding "parent.h" to both "child1.h" and "child2.h" it gives me the error "redefinition of class name" and if I only include it in one it gives these errors (http://imgur.com/L43qOWQ)

Comment: @JohnLongsocks that would be the reason for *include guards*. Hunt around a bit and you'll find info about them.